# TimeoutException while sending data via WebSocket

Tags: java, websocket, tomcat8, java-websocket, jsr356

I'm encountering `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` while sending data via WebSocket (*Tomcat8 JSR-356*). Refer the trace given below

```
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendPartialString(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:258)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendString(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:193)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointBasic.sendText(WsRemoteEndpointBasic.java:37)
```

I want to know if there are any circumstances under which we get this exception, apart from network latency related issues

**Note :** I'm facing this exception randomly. Tomcat version is **8.0.20**

Comment: Is this happening after some time? I've not used Tomcat websocket, but websockets do **close** automatically when there is an idle connection between server/client for a certain time.

Comment: Yes @Han! This is happening in few minutes after the session has been established. But I don't think it is because of the idle session. I constantly exchange data between the client and the server, which in turn doesn't let the WebSocket session to be idle.

Comment: This is a `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`, not a `SocketTimeoutException`. It is caused by some kind of concurrency timeout problem within the `java.util.concurrent` package. It doesn't have anything to do with the network whatsoever.

Comment: @EJP Inside `sendPartialString()` method, the data to be transferred is written to the output buffer and then the `CountDownLatch.await()` method is called to make the current thread wait for 20 seconds (which is the default timeout value). Once the the data is written to the output buffer, `CountDownLatch.countDown()` is called and the current thread resumes its operation. Otherwise, once the latch lapses the timeout value, TimeoutException is thrown explicitly by `throw new TimeoutException()`

Comment: So I think this is not actually the concurrency timeout problem. The main issue is it's taking a long time to write data to the output buffer. But I don't the know the reason. Any guesses or @EJP? If you still doubt that this is the concurrency issue, kindly let me know how

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was caused by sending data in chunks (**Chunked transfer encoding** or **chunk streaming**)

In my case was HTTP Post and the fix was sending content-length in headers.

But it may be the case that the receiver is not prepared to read data in chunks and thus times out waiting for EOF of data.